# How common are these Nuzlocke rules?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald, nuzlocke

I have Nuzlocked Pokemon Ruby and now I want to Hardcore Nuzlocke Pokemon Ruby. Now, the rule I am concerned about is:

You can only catch a first Pokemon per route.

This is a standard Pokemon rule, but I would twist what a route is. To be specific, I consider every floor of Dewford cave a route for itself. Why? Aron! If you would consider only Pokemon on your first entry as your Dewford cave encounter, there is no chance of you encountering Aron. On my first Nuzlocke, I solved this by picking that Repel after defeating Roxanne and then Repeling until I went down so my first encounter was Aron. Why am I now thinking otherwise? On first floor you have:

- Makuhita, lvl 24 Hariyama same attack stat as Blaziken,
- Zubat, just think about Crobat,
- Abra, even though you don't get Kadabra, to Brawly it makes no difference
- Geodude, the best possible encounter, Wattson - laughs in Ground. Flannery - laughs in quad resist plus super effective whatever. Norman - laughs in unable to set up Facade and tank monstrosity. Elite Four - laughs in Earthquake.

Also, I was playing on no repeat encounters. But I have not seen a single good use of Beautifly in game. While Dustox is a monstrosity that can just solo Brawly for you (and even Roxanne, lvl 15 destroys her with Confusion again and again).

How common are these rules in Nuzlocking?

Comment: What determines "common"?

Comment: It's very common to Nuzlocke with whatever rule modifications *you think are fun*. Nuzlocke isn't some strict thing you have to follow, it's for your fun. If you think this modification makes it more fun for you, do it. And if a rule *isn't fun*, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the whole cave counts as one.

The definition of a route is when the area text changes. For example, you walk to a different route, it'll say on the screen "Route xx".
The name doesn't change throughout the cave area, so it's only one route.

But you can use a different strategy I found on Gamefaqs:

> Each level of a cave is considered a different area but you can only catch one Pokemon in the entire cave. That way, if certain Pokemon only live near the bottom of the cave, you still have a chance of getting them.
> The trade off is once you encounter a Pokemon on a floor and choose to not catch it, you can't change your mind should the other floors yield worse encounters.

Answer (score 0):

On my nuzlockes I consider routes as separate areas with different names so for me Dewford cave floors wouldn’t count as separate ones.

Although, the routes can be counted to be only routes if they have the name “Route” on it so caves, special zones and poke safaris don’t count to get more consistency at knowing when to get pokemon.